# Jordan canonical form of a 5 x 5 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

If A is a complex 5 × 5 matrix with characteristic polynomial
f = (x − 2)$^3$
(x + 7)$^2$
and minimal polynomial p = (x − 2)$^2$
(x + 7), what is the Jordan form for A?

I have got an answer very close to the correct one of  \begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1       & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & -7 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0 & -7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
However I was wondering why the answer is not
 \begin{bmatrix}
    2       & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & -7 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0 & 0 & -7 \\
\end{bmatrix}
Where does the 1 come from in the second row?

Thanks

Comment: Your second answer has the wrong minimal polynomial

Comment: Remember the definition of minimal polynomial, 2 has degree 2 and then the max block has size 2x2

Answer (score 2):

A matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial factors as a product of *different* linear factors, so for your matrix to be similar to the lower matrix its minimal polynomial would have to be $\;(x-2)(x+7)\;$.

The one in the second row of the correct matrix is what "breaks" the diagonalizability of your matrix, and it comes from something called "generalized eigenvector", meaning: there are **not** three linearly independet eigenvectors related to the eigenvalue $\;2\;$, only two of them. The "third one" is the so-called generalized eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

We see that $\lambda = 2$ is a an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $3$ since $(x-2)^3$ shows up in the characteristic polynomial but the geometric multiplicity if only $2$ since the minimal polynomial doesn't split into distinct linear factors. Thus the matrix is not diagonalizable and the eigenvalue $\lambda= 2$ has a degenerative eigenspace. That $1$ off of the diagonal expresses these qualities.

Answer (score 1):

For each eigenvalue$~\lambda$, you may have one or more Jordan blocks, and the may have different sizes. The exponent of $(x-\lambda)$ in the characteristic polynomial gives the sum of all sizes of Jordan blocks for$~\lambda$, while the exponent of $(x-\lambda)$ in the minimal polynomial gives the size of the largest Jordan block for$~\lambda$.

So here for $\lambda=-7$ all blocks have size$~1$ (meaning "this part" is diagonalisable) and there are two such blocks. For $\lambda=2$ the largest block must have size$~2$ (so that you must have at least one nonzero off-diagonal coefficient, and this part is not diagonalisable), and the sum of the block sizes must be $3$, which is only possible with one block of size$~2$ and another block of size$~1$. This gives you all Jordan block sizes, and (up to permutation of the Jordan blocks) the Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 0):

Check your notes and review the minimal polynomial.  Note that a matrix will be diagonalizable if and only if every (distinct) factor in the minimal polynomial has exponent $1$.

In general, the exponent of a factor  in the minimal polynomial tells you the size of the *largest* associated Jordan block.